Deciphering workings of a printed circuit board for a night-light
I am new to electronics and am trying to understand how a particular circuit on a printed circuit board (photographs below) actually functions. The board represents the entire device which is a LED night-light that plugs directly into an AS/NZS 3312 230V AC power supply. The device turns on the LEDs when the surrounding illumination drops below some particular level.
Photograph 1 shows a front view of the board. The two diagonal slots are the points into which the original AS/NZS 3312 active (labeled "N") and neutral pins (labeled "L") were soldered.

Photographs 2 and 3 show slightly different views of the reverse side of the board. My reason for providing two photographs is so that the arrangements of the components can be clearly seen.


I think I have identified most of the components but I am not certain. My tally is:



ID
Side
Description
Notes




R1-1
reverse
resistor
value 330 kΩ ±5%


R1-2
front
SMD resistor
Labelled "EE" (rather than "33", I think). Unknown value


R2
front
SMD resistor
Labelled "475", 4.5 MΩ


R3, R4
front
SMD resistor
Labelled "103", 10 kΩ


R5
front
SMD resistor
Labelled "1820", 182 Ω


C1
reverse
capacitor
0.33 uF. Marked X2 MKP 0.33 uF 250VAC


C2
front
SMD capacitor (?)
Unknown value, no markings


CE1
reverse
Capacitor
100 uF 25V. The green electrolytic capacitor


DB1
front
Full-wave bridge rectifier (?)
Labelled "TL10F"


DZ1
front
Zener diode?
Labelled 2W 13V


Q1, Q2
front
NPN transistor
Labelled "J3Y"


F1
reverse
Resistor
100 Ω 5%. Perhaps 2W ? Why it is labelled "F1" not "R#", I don't know. Difficult to see because it is mounted vertically.


CDS
front
CdS photoresistor




I'd appreciate some help understanding how I might go about deciphering the workings of the board. At best, I would like to be able to sketch the actual schematic for the circuit. Failing that, I'd like to understand the likely role of each of the components. In addition to the general questions, I'd like to understand whether Q1 and Q2 are involved in the switching of the LEDs with changing illumination, or whether they are part of the power supply. ...

A capacitive dropper is used to create a low DC voltage. This design is non-isolated, so it should only be used when the circuit can't be touched.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitive_power_supply
C1 is the same in both circuits. CE1 in your circuit is C2 in my answer. E = Electrolytic.
The components on the right side may not exist in your module. For your application, regulation isn't necessary.
The transistors and CDS switch the LEDs when the ambient light is low.
F1 is probably a fusible resistor.
You should carefully trace your circuit and draw the full schematic. This is only a one-sided PWB and the traces are clearly visible. This is part of the learning experience. Yes, it is time consuming.
After you have drawn the transistors, you may need to ask another question regarding their exact purpose.

The usual way is to trace it out; one of the best ways is in a drawing package with layers, for example the open source package Inkscape.
You put the top and bottom images lined up (here bottom is reversed) and start tracing.  You draw everything you can see, and perhaps use a continuity meter for parts you can't.  Read all the component labels (on the board) and identicications on the parts, then look up all the datasheets for diodes, transistors etc.
Left to right: Top photo, Bottom photo reversed and slightly transparent,
Draw components, Start drawing tracks, Subtract photos.
Once you have that, you can start redrawing until you have a nice circuit diagram.
I recommend the EE.SE sticky answer about good diagrams which is full of very good advice.


Reason for labelling of  F1

Why it is labelled "F1" not "R#", I don't know.

It is probably a fusible resistor for protection against overload.
I haven't attempted to trace the full circuit, but from a quick look at the picture of the traces on the single layer PCB F1 appears to be in series between the L terminal and the rest of the circuit, which makes sense for the location of a fusible resistor.
For an example of a product the Tyco Electronics Flameproof Fuseible Resistors - FRN Series datasheet contains the following in the Key Features:


Flame-proof during fusing.
Ideal for use in safety-critical and circuit protection applications.
These resistors fuse in less than 60 seconds at 16 times rated power. (See table)


Query on labelling of supply pins
The question body says:

The two diagonal slots are the points into which the original AS/NZS 3312 active (labeled "N") and neutral pins (labeled "L") were soldered.

That seems to be reversed to me. I would expect that:

N is the neutral pin
L is the live (or active) pin


I agree that the labeling of the main supply pins seems odd. However, the LEDs clearly face to the front of the device. Yet, as you can see from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AS/NZS_3112 , the active pin (never referred to as the Live pin in NZ/Australia) is in the 10 o'clock position when facing the outlet, the Neutral pin is in the 2 o'clock position, and the Earth, if it exists, is at 6 o'clock.,
